# Sharing controller for multiple directives not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

[Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pz697c)

I am having an issue getting the ng-class to work in the `flipCard` directive's templates. Technically it does work, if I set the property immediate in the controller it will add the css class.

What it looks like to me in that children directives may be getting an independent copy of the controller instead of sharing the base `flipCard` directive's controller. So when I call `flipCtrl.move` it is calling the `flipCardOver` directive's instance of the controller as setting the property on the controller in the `flipCtrl.move` function is not updating the base parents `flipped` property, though console logging it says it is set to true.

**Goal:** Have a controller on `flipCard` that is shared with `flipCardBack`, `flipCardFront`, `flipCardOver`, `flipCardReset` While also allowing multiple `flipCard` directives on a page and not having conflicts.

What am I missing?

```js
angular.module('cardFlip', [])
  .controller('flipCardController', ['$scope', '$element', '$timeout', '$window',
    function($scope, $element, $timeout, $window) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.flipped = false;
      vm.moved = false;

      vm.originalTop = -1;
      vm.originalLeft = -1;


      vm.move = function(e) {

        vm.flipped = true;
        console.log(vm.flipped);
      };


      vm.reset = function() {
        vm.flipped = false;
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('flipCard', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      controller: 'flipCardController',
      controllerAs: 'flipCtrl',
      scope: true,
      transclude: true,

      // LOOK: this is the template that I am expecting to change
      template: '<div class="container"><div class="panel" ng-class="{ flip: flipCtrl.flipped, slide: flipCtrl.moved }" ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }

  })
  .directive('flipCardFront', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="front" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardBack', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="back" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardOver', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      link: function(scope, element, attribs, flipCtrl) {


        // LOOK: this is the event I am expecting to call move that sets flipped to true
        element.on('click', flipCtrl.move);
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardReset', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      link: function(scope, element, attribs, flipCtrl) {

        element.on('click', flipCtrl.reset);

      }
    }
  });
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

[ng-click] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel .pad {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.panel.flip .action {
  display: none;
}
.panel {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}
/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */

/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel .front {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: #6b7077;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .front {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg);
  transform: rotateY(179deg);
}
.panel.slide {
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
.panel .back {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .back {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="cardFlip">
    <div ui-view="main">
      <flip-card>
        <flip-card-front>
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;" flip-card-over="function(){return true;}">
            FRONT1
          </div>
        </flip-card-front>
        <flip-card-back>
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px;" flip-card-reset="function(){return true;}">
            BACK1
          </div>
        </flip-card-back>
      </flip-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I was stumped too, but then I realised - you haven't told Angular about the change using `scope.$evalAsync()` (safer than doing `$apply()` or `$digest()` in case there is already a digest happening). This is because you are handling the click yourself, rather than using `ng-click` (which triggers a digest, so doesn't have this problem).

Here is a [forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSZ2uz?p=preview) with it working.

```js
angular.module('cardFlip', [])
  .controller('flipCardController', ['$scope', '$element', '$timeout', '$window',
    function($scope, $element, $timeout, $window) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.flipped = false;
      vm.moved = false;

      vm.originalTop = -1;
      vm.originalLeft = -1;


      vm.move = function(e) {

        vm.flipped = true;
        console.log(vm.flipped);
      };


      vm.reset = function() {
        vm.flipped = false;
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('flipCard', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      controller: 'flipCardController',
      controllerAs: 'flipCtrl',
      scope: true,
      transclude: true,

      // LOOK: this is the template that I am expecting to change
      template: '<div class="container"><div class="panel" ng-class="{ flip: flipCtrl.flipped, slide: flipCtrl.moved }" ng-transclude></div></div>'
    }

  })
  .directive('flipCardFront', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="front" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardBack', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="back" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardOver', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      link: function(scope, element, attribs, flipCtrl) {


        // LOOK: this is the event I am expecting to call move that sets flipped to true
        element.on('click', function () {
            flipCtrl.move();
            scope.$evalAsync(); // tell Angular we did something
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('flipCardReset', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '^flipCard',
      link: function(scope, element, attribs, flipCtrl) {

        element.on('click', function () {
            flipCtrl.reset();
            scope.$evalAsync(); // tell Angular
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

[ng-click] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel .pad {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.panel.flip .action {
  display: none;
}
.panel {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  perspective: 600px;
}
/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */

/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel .front {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: #6b7077;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .front {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(179deg);
  transform: rotateY(179deg);
}
.panel.slide {
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
.panel .back {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  transform: rotateY(-179deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .back {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="cardFlip">
    <div ui-view="main">
      <flip-card>
        <flip-card-front>
          <div style="width:50px;height:50px;" flip-card-over="function(){return true;}">
            FRONT1
          </div>
        </flip-card-front>
        <flip-card-back>
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px;" flip-card-reset="function(){return true;}">
            BACK1
          </div>
        </flip-card-back>
      </flip-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice, I would have never figured that out. I am still figuring out the $apply and $compile stuff. Thanks man this works 100% as I would hope, I dropped a hand full of the directives on the page and they all handled their own state as well.

Comment: Look up how Angular works, it will help you understand what is going on. Basically, it does dirty checking of every watched expression every digest cycle, and if the value of the expression has changed, it does something in response. If nothing initiates that digest cycle, then Angular never sees the change and can never react accordingly. Most built-in Angular functionality takes care of this for you, but as soon as you step outside Angular, you have to remember to tell it when something might have changed.

Comment: Good to know thanks for the brief explanation I will have to look up more on it.